# Difference between $\int_0^1\log(x)\, \mathrm dx$ and $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

What is that different between $\int_0^1 \log(x)\, \mathrm dx$ and $ \int_0^1\frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm dx $?

While $\int_0^1\log(x) \, \mathrm dx =-1$, so it does converge, $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm dx $ diverges, but both $\log(x)$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ diverge at $x=0$.

I thought that both integrals are divergent because graph's area is infinite.

Comment: If you mean that the area between the curve and the $x$-axis is infinite, it's finite and equal to $1$ for $\log x$; it's equal to the integral by definition (of area, not the integral).

Comment: @anomaly um... I thought that ln(0) is -infinite so it diverges. But why? It didn't diverges? I wan't to know that....

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The surprising implication of these examples is that a Lebesgue integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ can converge even if either $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ diverges (or even both, if we replace $f(x)$ with $(f(x)+f(a+b-x))/2$). As you've noted, $\int_0^1\ln xdx=[x\ln x-x]_0^1=-1$ because $\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln x=\lim_{x\to 1}x\ln x=0$. Basically, the area is finite (or on a Riemann definition, undefined but certainly not $\pm\infty$), but that of a shape that becomes infinitely long at one end. *That's not a contradiction.* To take an example that's even easier, $\int_0^1x^{-1/2}dx=[2\sqrt{x}]_0^1=2$.

Comment: Is it possible to say "area ...  becomes infinitely long"? I would assume an area is a number...

Comment: @user What I mean is the shape we're looking at has finite area but in some places has infinite length, or width our whatever we call it.

Comment: @user They meant to say that the curve bounding the area is infinitely long, but the area is still finite. Its similar to the idea of [Gabriel's Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn), in that case the Surface is infinitely long but the volume is finite.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^1 \log(x)\,dx$ fails to exist as a Riemann integral, but exists as a Lebesgue integral, and as an improper Riemann integral.